# Set filter with regex in query with PHP's MongoDB\Driver\Query class

Tags: php, regex, mongodb, php-mongodb

Using MongoDB with PHP's [MongoDB driver](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php) I am not able to filter search results with regular expressions. In the manual there are no examples given how to use the "filter" option: [MongoDB\Driver\Query](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-query.construct.php).

```
 $manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
 $filter = array(?????);
 $options = array("projection" => array("fieldname" => 1));
 $query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
 $cursor = $manager->executeQuery("dbname.collectionname", $query);
 foreach($cursor as $document) {
    var_dump($document);
 }
```

I tried about 20 different possibilities but can't find the answer. Queries without regular expressions work fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am stupid. This:

```
'fieldname' => array('$regex' => 'm')
```

will find all documents with an "m" somewhere in the field "fieldname".

Comment: Is that what you wanted or do you still have some sort of question?

Comment: @ArSeN That's it, thank you! Should I delete the whole thing or leave it for others?

Comment: I think you should delete it, if you feel that it will not really help other people (e.g. because it is in the docs already).

Comment: @ArSeN I will delete it, before that, can you post the link to the docs? Thank you!

Comment: I do not have the link, sorry, I may have phrased that unprecise. I meant if you find that it is actually clear by reading the docs, or something like that.

Comment: @ArSeN For me not, I had to mix different examples of different websites other than the docs, in the docs I didn't find any answer to this. But I guess, for someone who used the old PHP driver for MongoDB this wouldn't have been any problem. It could help people who are really new to this I guess... So I would prefer to leave it but I'm really not sure...

Comment: @MichaelKäfer Please do not delete it, I had the same problem and currently this is the second result in google and the first, that answers the question, how to use regex with this mongoDB-driver.

Answer (score 3):

I was struggeling with the same problem, after moving from the deprecated mongo-driver to the new mongodb-driver. The accepted answer is good, so far. But this additional information may be helpful, too:

The **old driver** (see [php.net](http://php.net/manual/de/class.mongoregex.php)) requires the complete regular expression,  including slashes, like this:

```
$query1 = [ 'field' => new MongoRegex("/d+/i") ];
```

The **new driver** needs the slashes removed. Also, there are two ways to submit regular expressions, see [mongodb-driver-board](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/issues/186#issuecomment-264863921):

```
$query1 = [ 'field' => [ '$regex': => '\d+' ]];
$query2 = [ 'field' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex('\d+'), 'i'];
```

Note that common reg-ex-flags are coming as the second parameter. Of course, you are free to leave, them. As I did in the first line. By the way, at the end, it looks like both ways are translated to the same:

```
{"field":{"$regex":"\d+","$options":"i"}}
```

If you want to keep it dynamic, because you don't know if it's a search string or a regular expression, here is a code example:

```
if(@preg_match($value, null) !== false){

     $value = new MongoDB\BSON\Regex(trim($value, '/'), 'i');
     // alternatively you may use this:
     // $value = array('$regex' => trim($value, '/'));
     // with options, it looks like this:
     // $value = array('$regex' => trim($value, '/'), '$options' => );''
}
$search = array($field => $value);
$options = [
     "skip" => 0,
     "limit" => 10,
     "projection" => NULL
];

$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($search, $options);
$cursor = $this->mongo->executeQuery($database.'.'.$collection, $query);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The explanation helped.